# Custom view with email parameter in django changing the url and showing http status code 301,302

Tags: python, django

myapp model:

```
class GroupMailIds(models.Model):
    local_part = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        verbose_name='local part',
        help_text=hlocal_part
    )
    address = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='domains')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.address
```

In myapp urls.py:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.http import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('groupmailids/<str:email>/details',
         views.get_groupmailid_details, name='get_groupmailid_details'),]
```

myapp views.py:

```
def get_groupmailid_details(request, email):
    data = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        try:
            groupmailid_obj = GroupMailIds.objects.filter(address=email)[0]
            print(groupmailid_obj, '--------groupmailid_objjjjjjjj')
        except Exception as e:
           groupmailid_obj = None
        if groupmailid_obj:
            data.update(
                {'groupmailid_id':groupmailid_obj.id,
                 'address':groupmailid_obj.address,
            })

        print(data)
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

But when in browser I use the url:
`localhost:8000/admin/myapp/groupmailids/newgroup@saintmartincanada.com/details` it displays the main menu with message:

```
Group email id with ID “newgroup@saintmartincanada.com/details” doesn’t exist. Perhaps it was deleted?
```

The above code worked for sometime very well, but suddenly stopped working, in the console can see trace log messages like:

```
"GET /admin/myapp/groupmailids/newgroup@saintmartincanada.com/details HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[12/Jan/2022 18:18:22] "GET /admin/myapp/groupmailids/newgroup@saintmartincanada.com/details/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[12/Jan/2022 18:18:23] "GET /admin/myapp/groupmailids/newgroup@saintmartincanada.com/details/change/ HTTP/1.1" 30
```

Unable to fix this issue. Why is it appending '/change' to the url? and returning to the admin page in GUI? It is showing http status code 301, 302 in the logs ? I am using django 3.2 , python 3.7
Please can you suggest the correct code?
I have also tried APPEND_SLASH= TRUE and ensured thae trailing slash for the urls in the urls.py file, but it displays 302 code

Comment: You said it used to work, then did not work anymore: you should have make some changes, so don't you have a previous working version?

Comment: And I do not understand why you have `/admin/myapp/` in your url, does it occur in the admin part?

Comment: @Christophe i reset to lower level of git and and tried, still gave the same result. Actually the view is not getting called with the url at all. Checked by adding print statement at the beginning of the view code

Comment: @Christophe yes it is a custom view at this url in the admin part. But the JSON response is not rendered in any template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it. In the project urls.py I need to add the myapp urls before adding the default django admin urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('admin/myapp/',include('myapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```